# How Can I Post Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is the first time I deal with AJAX requests, and I have a problem with my code I wrote.

The API data is like the following:

```
"data": {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Big Mac beef burger",
    "description": "Big Mac beef burger with tomato slices and mayoneez",
    "image": "http://spoon.mtech-ins.com/uploads/products/big_mac.jpg",
    "price": 100.52,
    "basic_price": true,
    "provider_name": "Mcdonald's Restaurant egypt",
    "has_offer": true,
    "discount": 20,
    "discount_price": 80.416,
    "favorite": false,
    "product_additions": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Size",
            "required": true,
            "multiple": false,
            "product_addition_items": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Small",
                    "price": 20
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Medium",
                    "price": 50
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want only to only add `"Product_addition_items"` in my request which is nested from `"product_additions"`

My two problems are:

1. How to pass data to this deeply nested array (product_addition_items)
2. How to pass an array in the request body?

This is the code I wrote:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: `http://spoon.mtech-ins.com/api/admin/v1/addAddition/5`,
      headers: {
        Authorization:
          'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9zcG9vbi5tdGVjaC1pbnMuY29tXC9hcGlcL2FkbWluXC92MVwvdXNlcnNMb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTUyOTU5NzU3NywiZXhwIjoxNTM3MzczNTc3LCJuYmYiOjE1Mjk1OTc1NzcsImp0aSI6IkY1azBEQkk1MEhrdm5saHEiLCJzdWIiOjE0OCwicHJ2IjoiODdlMGFmMWVmOWZkMTU4MTJmZGVjOTcxNTNhMTRlMGIwNDc1NDZhYSJ9.XKNfm6cxBQnfKaEDMxsVK0vTETzIp6uisA0UwB0Q2-Q'
      },
      data: {
        name: product.name,
        required: product.required,
        multiple: product.multiple,
        options: options
      },
      success: data => {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: err => console.log(err)
    });
```

And I'm sure this is wrong as it didn't work, but I don't know exactly what to do

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `method` key instead of `type`. Try this

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: `http://spoon.mtech-ins.com/api/admin/v1/addAddition/5`,
  data: {
    name: product.name,
    required: product.required,
    multiple: product.multiple,
    options: options
  },
  success: function(data, status, xhr) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass an array to the request body you just need to call a function with a response parameter. the response parameter receives whatever object or value the function is receiving at a successful request.

```
success: function (data) { // here data is the response parameter
                response($.map(data, function (eachData) {  //map is used to iterate each value if it contains a list or array
                    // do whatever you want to do with each data
                ))
            }
```